# How to deduct quantity in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, xampp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCzkB.png)I'm trying to get the difference of Quantity and ItemBought in my Database and update the Quantity column based on what is the difference between the two.

I tried different SQL code for this one, but I always got the same error

Try
            getConnection()

```
        sql = "SELECT (Quantity - ItemBought) AS [Quantity] FROM products WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode;"

        cmd = New MySqlCommand
        With cmd
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = sql
            .Parameters.Clear()

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", formPOS.ProductCodeTB.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemBought", formInventory.quantityTB.Text)
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If result = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Error in updating the selected product!")
            Else
                MsgBox("Successfully updated the selected product!")
            End If"
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this?

Comment: seems your connection string is not working

Comment: square brackets are a sqlserver thing mysql won't like them. If you are using mysql try single quotes.

Comment: are you trying to update or select?

Comment: update the database sir

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE the table and with the modified value and refill the gridview. It will directly change the table value.

Or

If you are looking for temporary change of data means follow the below step:

```
"SELECT Quantity AS [Quantity] FROM products WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode;"
```

Then subtract the ItemBought then display on the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `exececutenonquery()` so I believe you trying to update your products table.

```
 sql = "UPDATE products set Quantity = (Quantity - @ItemBought) WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode;"

        cmd = New MySqlCommand
        With cmd
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = sql
            .Parameters.Clear()

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", formPOS.ProductCodeTB.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemBought", formInventory.quantityTB.Text)
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If result = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Error in updating the selected product!")
            Else
                MsgBox("Successfully updated the selected product!")
            End If"
```

Comment: I Tried the new SQL code you suggested sir, but still not working

Comment: updated the sql query string. try now and let me know the error details.

Comment: still not sir, it just goes to the  "If result = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Error in updating the selected product!")" statement

Comment: What's the value of your formPOS.ProductCodeTB.Text and formInventory.quantityTB.Text, our productcode existed in your db, it should return 1, if not it will return 0

Comment: ProductCode ItemDescription UnitPrice Quantity ItemBought
123 ALUMINUM 60 20 10

Comment: so far I've tried the query and its working. My suspicion is that your product code is empty. Can you add breakpoint and debug?

Comment: did You made public for those 2 textboxes since You are trying to reach them from different form ?

Comment: Yes, it is all public

Comment: Cant add debug and breakpoint sir, Since the code itself is running without error, its just that the database does not change its value

Answer (score 0):

Just got the right answer, I solved it by setting the right TextBox and right Form of the column ProductCode

```
Try
        getConnection()

        sql = "UPDATE products SET Quantity = (Quantity - @ItemBought) WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode;"

        cmd = New MySqlCommand
        With cmd
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = sql
            .Parameters.Clear()

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", formPOS.ProductCodeTB.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemBought", formQuantity.quantityTB.Text)
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If result = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Error in updating the selected product!")
            Else
                MsgBox("Successfully updated the selected product!")
            End If
        End With
```